# How can I get the "fallback font-family" with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, font-family

I am made a table of chars to test a pixel style font, and the browser shows the fallback font for some characters without char in this pixel style font.

[image]

The firefox devtool inspector shows the exact name of font, but I don't know how to get from javascript.

[image]

The html code is generated with a python script (it is not by hand) and it is this:

[image]

And I was trying with javascript code like this:

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("cell_x000102"),null).getPropertyValue('font-family')
"Telext50"
```

Comment: Of course, your JS finds out what font is set for that element, not what is set for a particular character within it. This seems to be something that the browser 'knows/decides' but there seems no way of finding out what font it's chosen using JS. What is your actual requirement? You can force any known 'gaps' to pick a character from a font you choose using CSS, does that help?

Comment: I need to know which cell (character) has "default font" to hide. Because I need to see for this custom font which chars exist.

Comment: So, as I iunderstand it, you have a custom font and you want to find out which characters do and which characters don't exist in it?

Comment: Would be easier to directly read the OTF/TTF file and get that info from there. For instance https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js will give you that very easily.